# how to use ternary operator to return a definite value or a block of code

Tags: operator-keyword, ternary

I was testing out the ternary operator in javascript to see if this would work. I want the function to return 1 if the number is zero or run through the loop and return the factorial. I don't know why it isn't working. please check the code below.

```
function factorialize(num) {
return (num==0)?1: (for( i=num-1; i>0; i--){
    num*=i
    console.log(num)
  }
  return num;)
}

factorialize(5);
```

Comment: Whats wrong with a plain old if?

Comment: _“I don't know why it isn't working”_ - because this operator expects _expressions_ as operands in those places, and this simply isn’t an expression. You can wrap it into an _IIFE_ to make it work (but you rather shouldn’t, this isn’t very readable.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Misorude I made use of an IIFE and it worked. Here is the code

```
function factorialize(num){
return (num==0)?1: (()=>{for( i=num-1; i>0; i--){
    num*=i
    console.log(num);
  }
  return num;})();
}
console.log(factorialize(5));
```